# google account chooser is not signing in android after publish app

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have implemented Google Drive rest API in my android app. When I was testing in debug mode  account chooser is properly appeared and after selection of an account it is working fine but once I upload it on playstore it is not getting selected after download my app from playstore

Comment: you have to use your release key store for generating sha key

Comment: i have generated sha1 key through android

Comment: you might be probably using debug.keystore for generating sha1. That will not work when you upload your apk to playstore, Use the keystore which you used to sign your application

Comment: thak you so much  it works